# In AJAX, variable value is not updated

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, velocity

Below is my jquery stuff, it works correct to call REST Service and response result return back to AJAX Success event.

But, every time when it executes then it does not update the variable "SelectedVal" (document.getElementById('Text1').value) and remain same which is the value set at first time.

it looks like, event is attached and not updated on each click.How it could be resolve ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var selectedVal = '';   
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();     

    var calendar = jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'Plan Issues',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {

               AJS.$(document).ready(function() {                       

                var dialog = new AJS.Dialog({
                width: 400, 
                height: 300, 
                id: "planissues-dialog", 
                closeOnOutsideClick: true
            });

            // PAGE 0 (first page)
            // adds header for first page
            dialog.addHeader("Plan Issues");

            // add panel 1
            dialog.addPanel("Issues Planning", "<table><tr><td>Enter issues ID (separated by comma):</td><td><input id='Text1' type='text' /></td></tr></table>", "panel-body");  //PROBLEM: "Text1" control is added here in dialog.

dialog.addButton("Submit", function (dialog)
{ 
selectedVal = document.getElementById('Text1').value; //PROBLEM:This returns every time same value even though, entering different value while dialog is popup. it preserve same value which was enter during first time and then after on each consequence , it remains same value.
if (selectedVal != '') { 
alert(selectedVal);     // PROBLEM: alert shows same value which set at first time.
var url = "http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/restresource/1.0/message/save/" + selectedVal;


jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data:  "finaldatapassed",
            cache: false,   
            success: function (resp, status, xhr) {
                alert('in success JSON');                   
                alert(status); //success

            },
            error: function(resp, status, xhr){
                  alert('in error json');
                  alert("Error: " + resp.e); 
            }
        });
}                                                       
});
```

});

Comment: _"it does not update the variable"_ - Right. Because at no point in your code do you do that. You need to do something in your `success` handler with the value from the response - out of context it's a bit hard to guess what to do, but maybe something like `document.getElementById('Text1').value = resp.someProperty;` (if your REST service is returning JSON presumably that JSON (once parsed) will have a property that is the value you want).

Comment: can You post the code where you are calling above function?

Comment: I think he means the status variable.

Comment: @nnnnnn,@SangjeevRai,@chris, I have updated above question to include extra stuff. This dialog is popup while selecting days from calendar and, this dialog contains  - "Text1" control which value is not getting updated in variable "SelectedVal", i have highlighted the issue at comments tag - "//PROBLEM:" in above stuff.

Comment: Any idea.. why this happen to not able to change the value. Please let me know if need more information ?

Answer (score 0):

success is defined as

```
Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
```

try

```
success: function (data) {
             alert('in success JSON');                   
             alert(data); //success
         },
```

Comment: Please let me know any other possible cause, i am still looking on this issue.

Comment: You would have to give use more information. E.g. instead of saying 'it does not work' tell us exactly what happens.

Comment: i meant,i had changed the success event like - function(data) instead of (resp,textstatus, jqXHR) and verified but, it remains same as mentioned above in first comment and not getting updated value for document.getElementById('Text1').value; even though, i add different value each time in "Text1" control of dialog.  <br/>(Also, i have updated the details in my first comment by adding "//PROBLEM" tag comment in stuff.

Comment: It's UI sequence work as follow: By selecting days in calendar, i got popup dialog open and here, it contains input textbox (i.e. "Text1" id) and submit button. I have added alert box on "submit" event and first time, it alert for correct value which i enter and after each consequence , i enter different value into "Text1" textbox though alert will show me same value is shown in first time and will not change until, i refresh whole page.

Comment: Use the Chrome Dev Tools and check on the Elements tab if you added <input id='Text1'...> multiple times. That may be the problem.